What symbol should I use for the vertical bar in set-builder notations in MathML?
In LaTeX, we often write \{ x \mid x \in X \land \Phi(x) \} for a set-builder notation. In MathML, it will be like
<mo>{</mo>
<mi>x</mi>
<mo>|</mo>
<mi>x</mi>
<mo>∈</mo>
<mi>X</mi>
<mo>∧</mo>
<mi>Φ</mi>
<mo>&af;</mo>
<mo>(</mo>
<mi>x</mi>
<mo>)</mo>
<mo>}</mo>

but what symbol should I use for the vertical bar? U+007C | or U+2223 ∣?


U+007C (|) is the character "Vertical line". Being part of the Basic Latin block, it has no special meaning, and it can be used in any place where a vertical bar is required. In fact, it has a lot of uses in many fields.
U+2223 (∣) is the character "Divides". It has a sister, "Does not divide", U+2224 (∤). Being part of the Mathematical Operators block, it is used to represent divisors: 3∣6 should be read as "three divides six" or "three is divisor of six".

In your case, I would use U+007C character, since in the set-builder notation, the vertical bar is just a visual separator.
